# Vim copy/paste from clipboard while keeping indentation

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

I am using Putty on Windows to connect to a Linux server.

On the Linux server I am using Vim to edit code files.

I am using my mouse to select an area to copy and then right click to paste the copied code.

So far I am aware of 2 settings that alter this copy/paste behavior:

- :set paste
- :set autoindent

**Sample YAML file:**

```
a1: value1
a2: value2
a3:
  a4: value4
a5:
  a6: value6
  a7:
    - value7

b1: value1
b2: value2
b3:
  b4: value4
b5:
  b6: value6
  b7:
    - value7
```

**What I want to do:**

Copy the whole "a" code sample under b3: in the "b" code sample while keeping the original indentation.

```
b1: value1
b2: value2
b3:
  b4: value4
  a1: value1
  a2: value2
  a3:
    a4: value4
  a5:
    a6: value6
    a7:
      - value7
b5:
  b6: value6
  b7:
    - value7
```

**Outcome:**

All combinations (paste, autoindent), (paste, noautoindent), (nopaste, autoindent), (nopaste, noautoindent) are incapable of performing pastes correctly. They all mess up the indentation in 1 way or another.

Is there any solution to this issue without using yank/p to copy/paste. Using a mouse is so much better in my opinion when you are not on a serial console.

Comment: `:h ]p`, `:h ]P`?

Comment: @r_31415 Can you provide an example on how to use it ?

Comment: Did you read the help files? Did you press `]p` in the desired region after copying your text?

Comment: p, ]p, ]P, "*]p, "+]p either output nothing (when I select with my mouse) or the last line from the multiple lines that I copied (from a different place with CTRL+C).

Comment: Since you're providing a self-contained example: https://i.imgur.com/PQtLjNm.gif  but that's not going to work if you're pasting from your clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, this preserves the indentation.

Comment: Not an answer to your question (hence a comment): `=ap` after pasting, in your context should do the work.

Comment: If you are selecting with your mouse, unless your vim is set up for it, you are likely selecting with your terminal. Using `V` (line select) to select the "a" values, pressing `y` to yank (=copy), then taking the cursor to the line with b4 and pressing `]p` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Biggybi I know it's not the solution, but it's the best copy/paste solution within 1 xterm window I have found so far. Anyways I tested `=ap` after pasting with my mouse. It says 17 lines indented, but indentation is still wrong. Only a7's indentatation seems to have been fixed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @r_31415 Another question. Do you know if the + and * registers can be used to copy/paste text between vim and the system clipboard with yip / ]P ?

Comment: @Subzero123  `yip` for yanking inside/inner paragraph will be copied to the selection clipboard and system clipboard by setting `clipboard=unnamed` and `clipboard=unnamedplus`, respectively. Now, `]P` to paste using the same indentation won't work either if you're copying text outside of a vim buffer. (cont)

Comment: Unfortunately, `=ap` or more precisely, \`[v\`]= to visually select previously yanked text, won't work reliably due to the ambiguity of indentation rules in languages with whitespace sensitivity. If you want to copy from your clipboard, I would do it as follows: press `p` as usual, visually select this text with \`[v\`] and manually indent by pressing  `>` as needed. If you have consistent `:tabstop` (or `:expandtab`) values, it should work correctly.

Comment: OK, I installed a Ubuntu VM just to test this gvim bs. Here are the results nnoremap Z "+yip nnoremap X "+]P . This allows you to 1. copy from one terminal window running vim to another terminal window running vim. 2. copy from one terminal window running vim into gedit program (or any other external program). 3. copy from gedit program and paste into terminal window running vim. The problem I still have is, I am not working directly on the Ubuntu server, I am using a Windows OS with PuTTY. Copy/pasting between 2 PuTTY windows or between windows OS and PuTTY does not work with "+yip and "+]P.

Comment: As I said using yip / ]P within 1 PuTTY window works great and I am going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste with Ctrl+Shift+V and keep the formatting,
run the command on vim

`:set paste`

After copying continue as normal by typing:

`:set nopaste`

Comment: PuTTY pastes with Shift + Insert from what I see. I tested it and it pastes the copied text at the beginning of the line instead of where my cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

you may also need notabs. If your original has tabs, copy paste may translate them to spaces. Avoiding tabs avoids the problem.

Comment: There are no tabs, only spaces. I use:

set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2

Answer (score 0):

normal mode: `"+p` OR `"*p`

OR

`:set paste`, S-insert, `:set nopaste`